# alternatives to rsync?

Tags: backup, rsync

I'm trying to script a backup system for several servers, some Windows, some Linux. I'd love to be able to use rsync but I can't (at least not in all situations, since some servers I can't install rsync to, and some are Win servers).

To add a wrinkle, some servers I have SSH access to, and some I have only FTP.

I've tested with wget in FTP mode with the "timestamping" option, and it seems to work pretty well regardless of platform. I'm also investigating rdiff-backup, though it appears that SSH is required.

Are there other options that may be more robust/reliable, that will do incremental backups regardless of platform and can function on either SSH or FTP?

Thanks for any ideas

Comment: If it is any help on the Windows machines, there are several ports of SSH and rsync to the Windows environment. I use SSH and rsync under Windows regularly via cygwin's ports.

Comment: I like [cwrsync](http://www.itefix.no/i2/node/10650) for rsync on Windows.

Comment: Try Crashplan. But it doesn't work over FTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Bacula

http://www.bacula.org/

Answer (score 3):

For windows boxes I have had good luck with delta copy (I know that doesn't technically answer your question and it is technically rsync but it works well for me)  I have also used backuppc http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/ it will let you choose by server how you are going to back it up.  I found it much easier to configure than bacula.

Comment: I know a few people with backuppc in production. They've used it for several years now and like it quite a bit.